# How to save all functions I entered in LispBox/Slime?

Tags: emacs, lisp, read-eval-print-loop, slime

Situation: I entered several functions while working with REPL in Emacs.
Problem: There is junk like "; Evaluation aborted" when I'm simply saving buffer.
What I want: clear descriptions of all the functions I entered in their latest revision.

Can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the best work flow method is to write your code in a separate buffer and evaluate in that, rather than enter the functions in the repl.

Assuming you have gone the repl way, I guess, C. Martin's solution to save the repl log and manually go through it are your only options.

If you entered the functions and vars into a separate package, you could go through the symbols in the package to help you decide what you want to keep.

E.g. to see all symbols created in the cl-user package:

```
(let ((p (find-package :cl-user)))
  (loop
     for s being the symbols in p
     when (eq p (symbol-package s))
     do (format t "~a~%" s)))
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't get it.  Are you entering definitions at the REPL and expecting to recover them later?  Just save a source file as you would in any other language.  Use C-x 2 to split your Emacs window in two.  Open a source file in one of them   C-x C-f foo.lisp.  Use C-c C-k, C-c C-r and friends (see SLIME menu) to compile / evaluate regions of your source code in the REPL.

Answer (score 5):

I've looked for something like this in the past and have been unable to find it. You're best off writing all your definitions in a separate buffer and using SLIME's extensive evaluation/compilation functions (C-c C-k loads an entire file, C-x C-e evaluates the last expression, C-c C-r evaluates a region, etc.), only directly entering into the REPL things you don't want to save.

Answer (score 4):

Um, `C-x o` or `C-x b` to get to the SLIME REPL buffer, then `C-x w` or `C-x C-s` to save it to a file. All the SLIME/CL stuff is a reader comment; you can either write a reader hack to reload the file treating the prompts as comments, or you can go through the file yourself to capture the pieces you want to save.

Comment: I know I should have realized this. I guess I'm still a little wide-eyed when it comes to Emacs. Thanks!